# Parallel Processing on Python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, ros

I am a beginner in python and multiprocessing so if the question seems naive please forgive me. 
I have two functions that I want to run at the same time. One is an openCV implementation of face recognition and the other is a standard python code.

```
def main():
    does(s) # a function call 

def face():
    recog.main() #another call
```

As you can guess, both the functions are the final end user functions that one has to call to implement the task. I want them both to run simutaneously.

Previous answers on this topic advise threading module but I have tried it and it does not work. The first func. to be called is executed first and then the second one. A friend of mine recommended rospy module. Is it the only way? Thanks in anticipation.

EDIT: In the answer to this, [Make 2 functions run at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957116/make-2-functions-run-at-the-same-time) , a user has written that threading actually won't make two functions run at the same time

Comment: *Previous answers on this topic advise threading module but I have tried it and it does not work* What did you try, Provide a [MCVE]. Also take a look at [Dead simple example of using Multiprocessing Queue, Pool and Locking](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20887555)

Comment: thread.start_new_thread(main())
thread.start_new_thread(face())
 
This does not run both of them simultaneously. Instead, finishes them up one by one. I tried threading module http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm But the result was the same.

Comment: If you aren't using ROS anyway, don't use rospy only running things in parallel. This is not what it is meant for and it will give you a unnecessary dependency on ROS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the [multiprocessing module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) for running two functions parallel. For what I did (changed to your situation):

```
import multiprocessing

def main():
    does(s) # a function call 

def face():
    recog.main() #another call

# Initiate two workers for the two functions
workerMAIN = multiprocessing.Process(target=main)
workerFACE = multiprocessing.Process(target=face)

# Start the workers
workerMAIN.start()
workerFACE.start()

# Wait until the functions have finished
workerMAIN.join()
workerFACE.join()
```

Comment: A big thanks SIr! I had tried the multiprocessing module out using the target keyword but it had not worked. A follow-up question, though. Is name a necessary argument? Thanks

Comment: No it isn't: in the [example in 16.6.1.1](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) you can see `Process(target=f, args=('bob',))`. So you can remove the name part! I will update my answer :)

Comment: For me, this was also the example I was looking for. Like @Spock I looked at proposed duplicates but wasn't able to get it working untill I implemented the code above