# Training different scikit-learn classifiers on multiple CPUs for each iteration

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy, scikit-learn, threadpool

I have a script that randomly generates a set of data and trains several classifiers to compare them against each other (it's very similar to http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_classifier_comparison.html):

```
from itertools import product

import numpy as np

from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier, AdaBoostClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB, MultinomialNB
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis

from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

names = ["Linear SVM", "Decision Tree",
     "Random Forest", "AdaBoost", "Naive Bayes", "Linear Discriminant Analysis",
     "Quadratic Discriminant Analysis"]

def griddy_mcsearchface(num_samples, num_feats, num_feats_to_remove): 
    classifiers = [
        SVC(kernel="linear", C=0.025),
        DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=5),
        RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=5, n_estimators=10, max_features=1),
        AdaBoostClassifier(), GaussianNB(),
        LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(),
        QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis()]

    classifiers2 = [
        SVC(kernel="linear", C=0.025),
        DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=5),
        RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=5, n_estimators=10, max_features=1),
        AdaBoostClassifier(), GaussianNB(),
        LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(),
        QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis()]

    X, y = make_classification(n_samples=num_samples, n_features=num_feats, n_redundant=0, n_informative=2,
                           random_state=1, n_clusters_per_class=1)
    X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.2)

    for name, clf, clf2 in zip(names, classifiers, classifiers2):
        clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
        score = clf.score(X_test, y_test)
        # Remove 40% of the features.
        clf2.fit(X_train[:,:-num_feats_to_remove], y_train)
        score2 = clf2.score(X_test[:,:-num_feats_to_remove], y_test)
        yield (num_samples, num_feats, num_feats_to_remove, name, score, score2)
```

And to run it:

```
_samples = [100, 200, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000, 10000, 20000, 50000, 100000]
_feats = [10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 10000]
_feats_to_rm = [5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 250]
for num_samples, num_feats, num_feats_to_remove in product(_samples, _feats, _feats_to_rm):
    if num_feats <= num_feats_to_remove:
        continue
    for i in griddy_mcsearchface(num_samples, num_feats, num_feats_to_remove):
        print (i)
```

The script outputs something like:

```
(100, 10, 5, 'Linear SVM', 1.0, 0.40000000000000002)
(100, 10, 5, 'Decision Tree', 1.0, 0.65000000000000002)
(100, 10, 5, 'Random Forest', 1.0, 0.90000000000000002)
(100, 10, 5, 'AdaBoost', 1.0, 0.65000000000000002)
(100, 10, 5, 'Naive Bayes', 1.0, 0.75)
(100, 10, 5, 'Linear Discriminant Analysis', 1.0, 0.40000000000000002)
(100, 10, 5, 'Quadratic Discriminant Analysis', 1.0, 0.84999999999999998)
(100, 20, 5, 'Linear SVM', 1.0, 1.0)
(100, 20, 5, 'Decision Tree', 0.94999999999999996, 0.94999999999999996)
(100, 20, 5, 'Random Forest', 0.80000000000000004, 0.75)
(100, 20, 5, 'AdaBoost', 1.0, 0.94999999999999996)
(100, 20, 5, 'Naive Bayes', 1.0, 1.0)
(100, 20, 5, 'Linear Discriminant Analysis', 1.0, 1.0)
(100, 20, 5, 'Quadratic Discriminant Analysis', 0.84999999999999998, 0.94999999999999996)
(100, 20, 10, 'Linear SVM', 0.94999999999999996, 0.65000000000000002)
(100, 20, 10, 'Decision Tree', 0.94999999999999996, 0.59999999999999998)
(100, 20, 10, 'Random Forest', 0.75, 0.69999999999999996)
(100, 20, 10, 'AdaBoost', 0.94999999999999996, 0.69999999999999996)
(100, 20, 10, 'Naive Bayes', 0.94999999999999996, 0.75)
```

but the `clf.fit()` is now single-threaded.

Assuming that I have enough threads to run all classifiers for each iteration,  **How would I be able to train the classifiers using different threads for every iteration of `for num_samples, num_feats, num_feats_to_remove in product(_samples, _feats, _feats_to_rm)`?**

**And if I am restricted to 4 or 8 threads but I need to train >4 or >8 classifiers for each iteration, how is it done?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is less of an answer and more of a rough sketch of an answer to your first question,

> How would I be able to train the classifiers using different threads
>   `for every iteration of for num_samples, num_feats, num_feats_to_remove
>   in product(_samples, _feats, _feats_to_rm)`

I assume by this you mean that for each iteration of `for name, clf, clf2 in zip(names, classifiers, classifiers2):` you want `clf` and `clf2` trained on different processors.

Here is some working code as a starting point (it is poorly implemented, but the general idea is there):

```
from itertools import product

import numpy as np
import multiprocessing
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier, AdaBoostClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB, MultinomialNB
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis

from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

names = ["Linear SVM", "Decision Tree",
     "Random Forest", "AdaBoost", "Naive Bayes", "Linear Discriminant Analysis",
     "Quadratic Discriminant Analysis"]

# def mp_handler():
#     p = multiprocessing.Pool(8)
#     p.map(mp_worker, data) 

def mp_worker((name, clf, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, num_features_to_remove)):
    if num_features_to_remove == False:
        clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
        return ('score1', clf.score(X_test, y_test))

    clf.fit(X_train[:,:-num_feats_to_remove], y_train)
    return ('score2', clf.score(X_test[:,:-num_feats_to_remove], y_test))

def griddy_mcsearchface(num_samples, num_feats, num_feats_to_remove): 
    classifiers = [
        SVC(kernel="linear", C=0.025),
        DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=5),
        RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=5, n_estimators=10, max_features=1),
        AdaBoostClassifier(), GaussianNB(),
        LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(),
        QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis()]

    classifiers2 = [
        SVC(kernel="linear", C=0.025),
        DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=5),
        RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=5, n_estimators=10, max_features=1),
        AdaBoostClassifier(), GaussianNB(),
        LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(),
        QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis()]

    X, y = make_classification(n_samples=num_samples, n_features=num_feats, n_redundant=0, n_informative=2,
                           random_state=1, n_clusters_per_class=1)
    X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.2)



    for name, clf, clf2 in zip(names, classifiers, classifiers2):

        p = multiprocessing.Pool(2) #set to 2 for using two processors; one processor per classfier
        #The integer parameter you pass to Pool is equal to the number of SETS of classifiers you have
        data = (name, clf, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, False), (name, clf, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, num_feats_to_remove)
        res =  p.map(mp_worker, data) #this splits the two classification tasks acrpss two separate processors
        for i,j in res: #parse the results
            if i == 'score1':
                score1 = j
            else:
                score2 = j

        yield (num_samples, num_feats, num_feats_to_remove, name, score1, score2)

if __name__ == '__main__':


    _samples = [100, 200]
    _feats = [10, 20]
    _feats_to_rm = [5, 10]
    for num_samples, num_feats, num_feats_to_remove in product(_samples, _feats, _feats_to_rm):
        if num_feats <= num_feats_to_remove:
            continue
        for i in griddy_mcsearchface(num_samples, num_feats, num_feats_to_remove):
            print (i)
```

If I misunderstood your question, then the general principle in the code above can be modified to suit your needs. I draw from the the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20887555/dead-simple-example-of-using-multiprocessing-queue-pool-and-locking) in the code above.

Comment: What is with the double parenthesis in the mp_worker function?