# Fastest method for Brute Force?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading, boost-thread, brute-force

I'm trying to brute force a ZIP file for a school project and realized that's very **slow** (*about 1600 Tries/Sec*).
Is it any method that allows to *run multiples tries at the same time* or *split the whole process* without *slowing it down*? I heard about the `thread` module but not sure if that's reall what I need ;)
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use multiprocessing module

take a look at this : 
https://pymotw.com/3/multiprocessing/basics.html

[Dead simple example of using Multiprocessing Queue, Pool and Locking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20887555/dead-simple-example-of-using-multiprocessing-queue-pool-and-locking)

by using multiprocessing you can split the job between your cpu cores